# return value in function when using defer

Tags: go

I have some problem with using 'defer' about the return value. I tried to run one test function in different way (only the definition of i is different), but the result is different. So, I'm confused about the different return value. Here is the problem:

function 1:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("a return:", a()) // return value: 0
}

func a() int {
    var i int
    defer func() {
        i++
        fmt.Println("a defer1:", i) // print " a defer1: 1"
    }()
    return i
}
```

return value:

```
a defer1: 1
a return: 0
```

function 2:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("a return:", a()) // return value: 1
}

func a() (i int) {
    defer func() {
        i++
        fmt.Println("a defer1:", i) // print " a defer1: 1"
    }()
    return i
}
```

return value:

```
a defer1: 1
a return: 1
```

One of the return values is 0, the other is 1. So, the question is what's the difference between the two function.

Comment: The given answer is correct, but the real lesson to be learned here is *don't modify returned values from within a `defer`*. It makes code very difficult to reason about and troubleshoot.

Comment: @Adrian: That is not the lesson to be learned. For example, read the Go experts: https://www.gopl.io/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what's the difference between the two functions?

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to
>   the moment the surrounding function returns.
>
> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
>   actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are
>   invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the
>   reverse order they were deferred.
>
> if the deferred function is a function literal and the surrounding
>   function has named result parameters that are in scope within the
>   literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result
>   parameters before they are returned. If the deferred function has any
>   return values, they are discarded when the function completes.

---

The difference is a surrounding function with a named result parameter

```
func a() (i int)
```

versus a surrounding function with an unnamed result parameter

```
func a() int
```